# jQuery draggable Bootstrap Tooltip slower than mouse error TypeError: a.$element is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, draggable

I have a draggable element (pin) which shown a tooltip on mouseover and deletes it on mouseout:

```
$('.pic').on('mouseover', '.pin', function(e) {
    $(this).tooltip({
        placement: function (context, source) {
            return "left";
        }
    });
    $(this).tooltip('show');
});

$('.pic').on('mouseout', '.pin', function(e) {
    $(this).tooltip('destroy');
});
```

But when I drag the pin with the mouse fast so that the pin itself lags behind the mouse pointer, it thrown tens of errors "TypeError: a.$element is null". I tried:

```
$('.tooltip').remove();
$('.tooltip').tooltip('destroy');
$('.pin').tooltip('destroy');
```

but none of these solve that.

How can I stop the tooltip errors when dragging the element faster than pointer?

That was Firefox. Chrome says: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trigger' of null"

Comment: can you create js fiddle?

Comment: Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/linuxoid/9w4y2cyp/ . But it's strange, there are no errors in Fiddle but I have them on my site

Comment: so may be some js conflict!!

Comment: please check it out now, now I've got errors. I've changed Bootstrap 4 to 3 (cos that's what's in the CMS) and changed tooltip('dispose') to tooltip('destroy'). So, looks like these are errors from dragging, not from tooltip. https://jsfiddle.net/linuxoid/9w4y2cyp/72/

Comment: update changed fiddle url!!

Comment: I have: https://jsfiddle.net/linuxoid/9w4y2cyp/72/